# scale a pod based on metrics from an other pod with custom metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, hpa

hope some can help but i try to scale a pod with custom metrics from a other one, if yes how should be a prometheus-adapter config lock like? Sadly i don't get it to work.

I tried something like this:

```
- seriesQuery: 'custom_metric{app="pod_where_metrics_come_from"}'
  name:
    matches: "^(.*)"
    as: "${1}_per_second"
  metricsQuery: 'sum(rate(<<.Series>>[2m])) by (<<.GroupBy>>)'
```

thx for all possible help :)

Comment: do you have a prometheus metrics that you want to use in HPA?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://itnext.io/horizontal-pod-autoscale-with-custom-metrics-8cb13e9d475) article ? I guess it might be helpful.

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu, yes i do have Prometheus metrics. And mario its not really helpful at all it just show how to auto-scale a pod with custom metrics. But i want to scale a pod based on custom metrics from an other pod (like a gateway, which just root to the original pod)

Comment: How this metrics are exposed ? Basically you can auto-scale a `Deployment`, specified under `spec.scaleTargetRef` in your `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` definition, based on any metric, including [`External` one](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-metrics-not-related-to-kubernetes-objects). You just need to configure your `metrics` properly and make them available for your `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` so it can make its scaling decision based on them. They don't have to be related in any way with `Pods` which are subject to auto-scale.